# Java NullPointerException - Short Program

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, program-entry-point

I'm new in programming in Java and I do not understand what's going on in my code.

It tells me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.Country.addMine(Country.java:37)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Java Result: 1
```

My main.java is simple:

```
    Continent Europe = new Continent("Europe");
    Country asd = new Country("asd", Europe);
    Mine mine = new Mine(100,100,100,100);
    System.out.println(mine == null);
    asd.addMine(mine); //dies here
```

this is addMine method:

```
public void addMine(Mine mine) {
     System.out.println(mine == null);
     this.mines.add(mine); //dies here
     this.iron += mine.iron;
     this.gold += mine.gold;
     this.stone += mine.stone;
     this.wood += mine.wood;
     System.out.println("Mine has been successfully added to the country with the given values."
);
```

and Mine.java is:

```
public class Mine implements Building { //Building is an empty interface :)
    protected int iron;
    protected int gold;
    protected int stone;
    protected int wood;
    public Mine(int iron, int gold, int stone, int wood) {
        this.iron += iron;
        this.gold += gold;
        this.stone += stone;
        this.wood += wood;
    }
}
```

As You can see I wrote 2 println-s and both of them were false, so the object exists! I don't understand why it shows NullPointerException :(

Comment: Im guessing 'mines' is some sort of dynamic list in Country? Is it initialized before you try to add to it?

Comment: Have you initialized mines? which is an arraylist i guess.

Comment: Can you post us how is did you declare `mines` ?

Comment: @JeremyD: It can't be an array, given that arrays don't have an `add` method.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I was thinking of an arraylist but mistyped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is failing:

```
this.mines.add(mine); //dies here
```

... then I suspect `mines` is a null reference. You haven't shown any declaration for it *or* initialization - but that should be your first port of call. Chances are it's just a case of changing:

```
private List<Mine> mines;
```

to

```
private List<Mine> mines = new ArrayList<Mine>();
```

or something similar.

Comment: oh! thank you :D it was protected List<Mine> mines, and now it works! :D

Comment: It is better to use private instead of protected except if you really need to use protected. Protected variables can be accessed by subclasses and this can have some potential risks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `mine` could be not `null` but what about `mines`? Which I guess it's a `ArrayList<Mine>` or something like that, did you inizialize it as `mines = new ArrayList<Mine>()`? (or whichever collection it is)

Answer (score 1):

Null pointer exception is thrown when you invoke method on reference that is null.

```
this.mines.add(mine); //dies here
```

`this.mines` reference is obviously equal to `null`.

Also try to make your reference variables names start with lowercase letters.

```
Continent Europe = new Continent("Europe");
```

->

```
Continent europe = new Continent("Europe");
```

Names with starting uppercase letters are 'reserved' for classes.

It's considered a good style in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You code fails in the

```
this.mines.add(mine);
```

at County class.

In order to bypass the error you should create a local variable inside the County class(in case you dont have it) which will be

```
private List<Mine> mines;
```

and you will initialise it by adding the following

```
mines=new LinkedList<Mine>();
```

The above thing can be written in one line of code but that is up to you.

```
private List<Mine> mines=new LinkedList<Mine>();
```

You can use any other implementation of List.